# Maui AppShell - Cascading menu(Expandable child menu elements)

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm trying to add a cascading menu using `MenuFlyoutItem` and `MenuFlyoutSubItem` in AppShell.xaml but it doesn't work.

Here the code

```
<Shell.FlyoutHeader >
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="MPC-Calculator"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>

<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open"/>
    <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Send to">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Bluetooth" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Desktop (shortcut)" />
        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Compressed file">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Compress and email" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Compress to .7z" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Compress to .zip" />
        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
    </MenuFlyoutSubItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="MPC" Icon="home_icon.png"  >
        <ShellContent
        Title="MPC-Calculator"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="MPC - File Demo" Icon="add_icon.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:MPCFileDemo}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="File Open Test" Icon="file_open.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:TestView}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>

    <MenuFlyoutSeparator  />
    <MenuFlyoutSeparator  />

    <FlyoutItem Title="Settings" Icon="tab_settings.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:SettingsView}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>

    <ShellContent Title="About"
                  Icon="info.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:AboutView}" />
```

Here is the output. As you can see the `<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Send to" />` is displayed I can't Display the sub elements when I click on it.

[image]

Comment: Guess context menu only supported for desktop apps, could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219789/is-it-possible-to-add-sub-menus-inside-a-single-menu-item-at-runtime-in-shell) for mobile or watch [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7345)

Comment: Thank Shaw for your comment. The [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7345) provided link is what I need.

Answer (score -1):

.NET MAUI desktop apps will display a menu bar, containing menu items, when they are added to any `ContentPage` that's hosted in a NavigationPage or a Shell app. Here's the xaml code below for your reference:

```
<ContentPage ...>

    <ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
        
        <MenuBarItem Text="File">
            
            <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Open">
                
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open to do something">
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
                
            </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
        </MenuBarItem>
        
    </ContentPage.MenuBarItems>

</ContentPage>
```

For more details, you can refer to [Display a menu bar in a .NET MAUI desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar?view=net-maui-7.0).

And your requirement is showing **child items** under `FlyoutItem` like below code snippet. Unfortunately, this is a feature request:[Feature Request New Navigation Bar to Mimic win ui Behavour In Shell](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7345) that hasn't been implemented as @Shaw pointed out. You can follow up on that thread.

```
 <FlyoutItem Title="Basic Input">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Basic Input"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SalesOrderPage}"
            Route="BasicInput" >
           <ChildItem x:Name="mnuInputVal" Text="Input Validations" Icon="" IconPosition="" />
           <ChildItem x:Name="mnubutton" Text="Button" Icon="" IconPosition="" />
            <ChildItem x:Name="mnuDropDownButton" Text="DropDownButton" Icon="" 
             IconPosition="" />    
        </ShellContent>
 </FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Did replace my code by your example and replacle "ContentPage" by "shell> and I get the complie error. "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NETSDK1127 The targeting pack Microsoft.Android is not installed. Please restore and try again. MPCMassPropertiesCalculatorMAUIBlazorapp C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets 376"

Comment: Did solve the bug by removing all mobile target TargetFrameworks in the csproj file,  But the output is a navigation bar in the content page. That<s not what I want, There is nothing in the navigation pane after did press the hamburger.

Comment: You need put the `ContentPage.MenuBarItems` in your MainPage.xaml instead of replacing it by `Shell`.

Comment: Because they are added to the `ContentPage`.